# Assign html value to cell

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to assign a bootstrap button to a table cell in my ASP.Net project dynamically as shown below:

```
cellN.InnerText = "11";
row.Cells.Add(cellN);
cellDomain.InnerText = "www.google.com";
row.Cells.Add(cellDomain);
cellIp.InnerText = "192.168.1.1";
row.Cells.Add(cellIp);
cellPorts.InnerHtml = "< button type = \"button\" class=\"btn btn-sm btn-port-info btn-danger\">80</button>";
row.Cells.Add(cellPorts);
MainTable.Rows.Add(row);
```

But it appears as a text in the output:
[image]

What is the point I have missed in this case?

Comment: OMG so sorry that was because i worked so many hours continually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be no space between `<` and `button`.